# Transform pixel coordinates from camera 2 to camera 3 in Kitty dataset

Tags: coordinate-systems, homography

Basically, I want to transform a point from the image of camera 2 (x_pixel_c2, y_pixel_c2) to a pixel point (x_pixel_c2, y_pixel_c3) in camera 3.

For a simple setup (no distortion parameters, no rectification), I would usually:

1. assign a certain distance to the point in C2
2. compute the coordinates in 3D space of C2 from the intrinsics
3. compute the World coordinates from the extrinsic matrix of C2
4. compute the 3D coordinates in C3 from its extrinsic matrix
5. project in pixel space of C2

For the Kitty dataset, I do not use this approach because of the distortion parameters (especially). In Kitty, we have the projection matrices for the 4 rectified cameras, which from what I understand, are the transformation matrices relating the 3D coordinates in Camera 0 to Camera X. However, from the tests I've made, this does not work:

```
pt_3d_cam0 = np.dot(inverse(P_rect_02), pt_cam_2)
pt_cam_3 = np.dot(P_rect_03, pt_3d_cam0)
```

I'm not sure the projection matrices move the referential back to camera 0 as it is mentioned. For instance, the points are closer to the expected coordinates if I add a translation in X equal to the amount of the baseline.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. If anyone has encountered a similar problem with Kitty, it would be appreciated if you could help.

Thank you!